# Bloquear acesso direto a uma URL via webconfig

Tags: asp, web.config

Tenho um sistema antigo em ASP clássico e preciso fazer algumas implementações. Tenho um arquivo `web.config` para está aplicação e gostaria de saber se através do mesmo é possível bloquear o acesso direto a uma URL de um vídeo.

Por exemplo: Caso o usuário tiver acesso a url do vídeo e colar na barra de endereços gostaria de bloquear ou redirecionar. Mas caso uma página especifica do sistema esteja utilizando essa URL ele deve conseguir acessar sem restrições.

Eu tentei algo como:

```
<rule name="assets">
   <match url="^assets/videos/([a-z0-9-]*)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="erro.asp" />
</rule>
```

Assim é possível bloquear o acesso direto via url. Mas também bloqueia o carregamento do vídeo nas outras páginas da aplicação.

Comment: Você quer bloquear o acesso direto a URL, mas se for usando a Tag video então está liberado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode checar a URL pelo Rerefer, assim:

```
<rule name="assets">
    <match url="^assets/videos/([a-z0-9-]*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^https?://www\.seusite\.com/pagina-especifica/.*$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="erro.asp" />
</rule>
```

No caso troque `^http://www\.seusite\.com/pagina-especifica/` pela sua página que será a única que poderá ter acesso aos vídeos

> **Nota:** ainda sim é possível "enganar" o navegador usando "modificadores" de headers, mas é algo um pouco mais difícil de fazer.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste mas ele não aceitou o meu conditions. Eu adicionei a seguinte pattern: "<add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^meus-cursos/curso/([a-z0-9-]*)/modulo/([0-9]*)/video-aulas/.*$" negate="true" />". Mas o vídeo é bloqueado nessa página também.

Comment: @alan assim `pattern="^https?://meusite.com/meus-cursos/curso/([a-z0-9-]*)/modulo/([0-9]*)/vid‌​eo-aulas/.*$"`

Comment: Sem sucesso. msm assim ele não continua aceitando o conditions! :/

Comment: @alan tem alguma outra regra? Tem como enviar o web.config inteiro?

Comment: @alan vou dar uma olhada, assim que conseguir testar lhe aviso ;)

Comment: OK! obrigado! ;)

Comment: Finalmente consegui. Depois de fazer vários testes não havia reparado que as barras depois de www e do nome do site eram invertidas. Também tive que remover o ".*$" do final. No final ficou assim: "<add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^https?://www\.afameducacional\.com.br/previa/EAD/meus-cursos/curso/([a-z0-9-]*)/modulo/([0-9]*)/video-aulas" negate="true" />" :)

Comment: Perfeito @alan !

Answer (score 1):

Não há forma de fazer o que você quer só com o web.config.

O que você pode fazer é um handler que o usuário acesse para ver o vídeo, e condicionar o acesso a uma variável de sessão.

Na página que o usuário deve acessar para poder ver o vídeo, você dá algum valor arbitrário à essa variável de sessão. No handler você verifica se a variável está com o valor necessário.

Talvez você queira dar um tempo de vida para essa variável também, assim o usuário vai precisar navegar para a página de novo depois desse tempo se quiser rever o vídeo.